# Dynamic folder name for Visual Studio Publish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to configure the file system Publish option within VS 2017 to deploy to a new folder based on either a date or an incremented build version?

i.e when I click publish i'd want it to goto "MyApp\v1" then the next time "MyApp\V2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few macros that you can use.

To do the date, use this Macro:

```
$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(yyyy.MM.dd))
```

or for a new ID, which I think you may want try:

```
$([System.Guid]::NewGuid())
```

If you want to do increments with an ID, I think you should define your own static function, which saves the previous ID and gets a new one. (You can work out that part)

```
$([Class]::Property)
```

See this page for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd633440(v=vs.100)